# folders and files on MacOS can't be deleted by any means

Tags: mac

I have some folders/files on my computer that I can't seem to delete.

```
 ▲ ~/Trash la
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   5 chris  staff   160B May 19 07:45 core-util-is
drwxr-xr-x   3 chris  staff    96B May 21 13:40 cross-spawn
drwxr-xr-x   4 chris  staff   128B May 21 14:41 crypto-random-string
drwxr-xr-x  10 chris  staff   320B May 21 15:21 debug
drwxr-xr-x   7 chris  staff   224B May 21 15:02 node_modules
```

if I try and delete anything in this `Trash` folder I get the following:

```
 ▲ ~/Trash sudo rm -rf core-util-is 
rm: core-util-is: Directory not empty
```

even though the folder is completely empty:

```
 ▲ ~/Trash/core-util-is ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  5 chris  staff  160 May 19 07:45 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 chris  staff  224 May 21 15:21 ..
```

Any suggestions? Should I just hide these files away and pretend they don't exist? backup, format and restore?

Answer (score 0):

One of my friend had a problem where he couldn't empty the trash via "empty trash" command. He asked me for a solution. I told him to Relaunch Finder and that worked. Try to Kill or Relaunch the Finder. (Are the files .DS_store).